# Is there any procedure to check below string as a condition in if statement?

Tags: javascript

```
var str='true && (true || false) && true';
if (str) {
    console . log('true');
} else {
    console . log('false');
}
```

Check above dynamic string as a condition true or false.

Comment: An `eval` function exists, but everythinkg which is passed to it will be evaluated, so be carefull with it. It may become a potential risk.

Comment: I'd question if this is even needed in the first place. Seems like an odd setup to try and achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `eval` function. Generally speaking `eval` evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string. For further info, please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

However, you should pay attention of the following remark, that you will in the link mentioned above:

> `eval()` is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed
>   with the privileges of the caller. If you run `eval()` with a string that could > be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running malicious code on the > user's machine with the permissions of your webpage / extension.

```js
var str='true && (true || false) && true';
if(eval(str)){
  console.log('true');
}
else{
  console.log('false');
}
```

Comment: As a caveat, please refer following before using: [Eval is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) and [When is JavaScript's eval() not evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil) and

Comment: @Rajesh answer restructured.

Comment: «eval is evil» :)

Comment: Thank man this will work for me.this will dangerous but I am not using any authentication process on it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a small parser:

```
 function evaluate(str){
   //remove all whitespace
   str = str.replace(/\s/g,"");
   //Parse stuff in brackets first:
   const first = str.indexOf("("), last = str.lastIndexOf(")");
   if(first != -1 && last != -1)
     str = str.substr(0, first) + evaluate(str.substr(first + 1, last)) + str.substr(last + 1);
  //split into or parts
  return str.split("||")
   //parse the or parts
   .map(sub =>
       //Evaluate the &&
       sub.split("&&")
          .every(el => el === "true")
   //evaluate the or parts
   ).some(e => e);
 }
```

So you can do:

```
 if(evaluate("true && false || false")) alert("works!");
```